# Nginx multiple locations for multiple React application

Tags: reactjs, nginx, react-router

I have 2 different React apps using React Router. I have the following structure on my Nginx conf:

```
# This is to serve main React App    
location / {
      root /apps/www;
      index  index.html index.htm;
      try_files $uri /index.html;
    }

# This is to serve secondary React App
 location /report {
    root /apps/www/report;
    try_files $uri =404;
    }
```

I have put both build files on the corresponding root folder.

However, when I open `https://hostname/report`, instead of going to the secondary React app, it goes to the main app, handled by its React Router, then redirected to NotFound page.

How to make Nginx location handle the routing to `/apps/www/report` ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using `root` directive incorrectly (check the difference between `root` and `alias` nginx directives). I think you should use a config like

```
root /apps/www;
index index.html index.htm;
# This is to serve main React App    
location / {
    try_files $uri /index.html;
}
# This is to serve secondary React App
location /report {
    try_files $uri /report/index.html;
}
```

You may also need to rebuild your second React app according to your `/report` prefix since all links to its assets should be generated with this prefix (or they obviously would be served with your first app). Check [this](https://medium.com/@svinkle/how-to-deploy-a-react-app-to-a-subdirectory-f694d46427c1) article for example.